# angular Failed to load resource error in inspector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am uploading dummy content using angular's ng-repeat.

```
var app = angular.module("homeApp", []);
app.controller("entriesView", function ($scope){
$scope.itemEntry = [            
{
    image: "img/112013-priscilla-600.jpg",
    title: "ymc",
    logo: "http://www.youmustcreate.com/site/wp-content/themes/youmustcreate/images/core/header-logo.jpg"
},

{
    image: "https://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/13/47/112013-priscilla-600.jpg"
}    
  ];

 });
```

HTML

```
<section class="miniframe-wrapper" ng-controller="entriesView">
    <section ng-repeat="itemEntry in itemEntry" class="miniframe">
    <img src="{{itemEntry.image}}" alt="img"/>
```

I noticed in inspector i am getting the `Failed to load resource` error however the images are appearing on my browser. Does anyone know what exactly is causing this issue. am i referencing my images correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ng-src instead of src in your image tags when using string interpolation. ng-src parses the string then assigns the src to the tag while vanilla html is looking for an image called "{{dataEntry.image}}"